# How to customize legend for a continuous size variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

My data is grouped based on size and shape. For shape I have chosen color to differentiate them and for size I have chosen the relative size to differentiate them. However, the plot that is generated has a legend that does not include all the size numbers. I want to customize the legend for size so that it shows all the sizes.

```
TMC_vs_SSA <- ggplot(surface_area, aes(x= specific_surface_area, y=TMC, color =Shape, size=Size))+
  
  theme_bw()+
  geom_point(alpha= 0.80)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15,20,17,18,19,5,3,11,13))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.001,0.01,1,100,10000,1000000,100000000,
                         10000000000,1000000000000,
                         100000000000000,10000000000000000, 1000000000000000000), 
                minor_breaks= minor_breaks) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(.001,0.01,1,100,10000,1000000,100000000,
                         10000000000,1000000000000,
                         100000000000000,10000000000000000, 1000000000000000000, 100000000000000000000), 
                minor_breaks = minor_breaks)

TMC_SSA_plot<- TMC_vs_SSA + xlab('Specific Surface Area (µm^2/g)')+
  ylab('TMC (#/L)')+ #ggtitle('Threshold microplastics concentration curve')
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 11))

TMC_SSA_plot <- TMC_SSA_plot + theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[[image]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what you did for the `x` and `y` scale you could set the breaks for the `size` legend via the `breaks` argument of `scale_size_continuous`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `ggplot2::mpg`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy, cty, color = class, size = cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = sort(unique(mpg$cty)))
```

[image]